# ImportError: cannot import name 'PKCS1_OAEP'

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a file using RSA with key length 2048 bits by generating public and private keys pair. When I am trying to import RSA crypto library, I am getting the error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'PKCS1_OAEP'

Below is the code which I am trying to implement.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

key = RSA.generate(2048, e=65537)
private_key = key.exportKey("PEM")
public_key = key.publickey().exportKey("PEM")

print (private_key)
fd = open("private_key.pem", "wb")
fd.write(private_key)
fd.close()

print (public_key)
fd = open("public_key.pem", "wb")
fd.write(public_key)
fd.close()
```

P.S I have installed the required package already. 
Any insights would be  much appreciated.

Comment: "I have installed the required package already..." And what package would that be?

Comment: Pycryptodome package

Comment: Check to make sure you don't also have pycrypto installed. The two packages interfere with each other.

Comment: @JamesKPolk yes you are correct I had installed both the packages, I removed pycrypto and the code is working fine now. Thanks